# how do you enable anonymous access to rest api in SharePoint 2016 on-prem?

Tags: sharepoint

I have disabled the `Require Use Remote Interfaces permission` and enabled the `Enable anonymous access` in Authentication providers, for Default Zone.

I've also disabled `ViewFormPagesLockDown` feature for the site collection and given the site collection anonymous access. What else do I need to do?

I keep getting ..

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (Forbidden) "

error on my page (works perfectly when logged in!).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Only configured Anonymous Access in CA and disable "Require Use Remote Interfaces permission" and "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode", then I can access list via Rest API anonymously.